# How to replace String value with regex

Tags: java, json, string, replaceall

> MOrris Example

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { month: "2006", amount: 100},
    { month: "2007", amount: 75}
  ],
  xkey: "month",
  ykeys: ["amount"],
  labels: ["amount"]
});
```

amount in ykeys and lables should be same as it is mentioned in Morris Example. Otherwise graph would not display because of error in `amount` format.

At moment my amount value is in this way

```
String amount = "[amount]";

amount="[amount]"
```

and i want value in this way

```
["amount"]
```

What would be easiest and preferred way to replace these values?

Comment: I think you can parse `amount` first using JSON.parse(), so you will get an array of strings, from where you can pick "amount" by using amountArray[0]

Comment: Why do you use String when amount is an array? String amount="[amount]"; is written by you or come like a string from another service that you can't touch?

Answer (score 3):

Why regex?

If you can achieve your task with simple calls to APIs which don't require regex, stick to them.

```
amount.subString(1,amount.length()-1);
```

Comment: amount.substring(1,amount.length - 1); in javascript

Comment: @Milaci Really!! ??

Comment: If Tatkal need to replace it on front-end. What really? For substring in js?

Comment: He didn't add javascript tag.

Comment: Ah ok, i didn't see that. I see only json and i thinked that was for some front-end stuff. Some ajax ..

Comment: See OP comment on my answer. OP is looking to add chars, not subtract.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex.

```
  amount = amount.replace("[", "[\"").replace("]","\"]");
```

Edited. OP cleared up what was needed. The above code is replacing `[` with `["` and `]` with `"]`.

The `"` is escaped within java with `\`

Comment: i get output as amount. it should be in this way ["amount"]